# Curl Token request to Spring RestTemplate Conversion

Tags: java, spring, curl, resttemplate

I am trying to convert a curl request, which is giving me a token into Spring's Resttemplate post request, but I am getting 403 - bad request

My Curl Request

```
curl -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=nu5yzeth9tektzf5egxuntp7&client_secret=uP2Xvr6SCKYgXgxxJsv2QkUG" 
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
  -X POST https://cloudsso.example.com/as/token.oauth2
```

Curl Response:

```
{"access_token":"HVURQ845OPJqs8UpOlef5m2ZCNwR","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599}
```

Now, Here is my Java code to implement above curl post request

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

MultiValueMap<String, String> bodyParamMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
bodyParamMap.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
bodyParamMap.add("client_id", "nu5yzeth9tektzf5egxuntp7");
bodyParamMap.add("client_secret", "uP2Xvr6SCKYgXgxxJsv2QkUG");

entity = new HttpEntity<>(reqBodyData, bodyParamMap);

restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, TokenDTO.class)
```

Resttemplate call response:

```
2019-12-04 11:10:16,483[0;39m [39mDEBUG[0;39m [[34mrestartedMain[0;39m] [33morg.springframework.core.log.CompositeLog[0;39m: Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
[30m2019-12-04 11:10:16,484[0;39m [39mDEBUG[0;39m [[34mrestartedMain[0;39m] [33morg.springframework.core.log.CompositeLog[0;39m: Writing [{"grant_type":["client_credentials"],"client_id":["nu5yzeth9tektzf5egxuntp7"],"client_secret":["uP2Xvr6SCKYgXgxxJsv2QkUG"]}] with org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter
[30m2019-12-04 11:10:17,976[0;39m [39mDEBUG[0;39m [[34mrestartedMain[0;39m] [33morg.springframework.core.log.CompositeLog[0;39m: Response 400 BAD_REQUEST
[30m2019-12-04 11:10:17,981[0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m [[34mrestartedMain[0;39m] [33mcom.ibm.ciscoApiIntegration.service.impl.CiscoAPIServiceImpl[0;39m: e::: 400 Bad Request
```

How can make the above curl request in `RestTemplate` working?

Note: https://cloudsso.example.com/as/token.oauth2 it's little modified for the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring RestTemplate POST Request with URL encoded data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49127240/spring-resttemplate-post-request-with-url-encoded-data)

Comment: My recommendation would be _not to do that at all_ and use an OAuth2 client that already understands this. There are several available, including one for Spring that integrates with RestTemplate.

Comment: You need to set the content type properly on the `HttpHeaders` and your `HttpEntity` is constructed wrongly (you aren't passing the headers).

Comment: @[chrylis-onstrike]- I was trying oauth2 client but wasn't able to find a working reference code, so I tried this, if you have any reference, please share it with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just solved the issue:

I had this in this

```
// wrong
//private HttpEntity<String> entity;
```

I changed it to this:

```
private MultiValueMap<String, String> parametersMap;
```

and changed it

```
// not working
entity = new HttpEntity<>(reqBodyData, bodyParamMap);
```

to this

```
// working
entity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyParamMap, headers);
```

Now it's working perfectly fine.

response:

```
2019-12-04 11:52:46,503 DEBUG [restartedMain] org.springframework.core.log.CompositeLog: HTTP POST https://cloudsso.example.com/as/token.oauth2
2019-12-04 11:52:46,521 DEBUG [restartedMain] org.springframework.core.log.CompositeLog: Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
2019-12-04 11:52:46,522 DEBUG [restartedMain] org.springframework.core.log.CompositeLog: Writing [{grant_type=[client_credentials], client_id=[nu5yzeth9tektzf5egxuntp7], client_secret=[uP2Xvr6SCKYgXgxxJsv2QkUG]}] with org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter
2019-12-04 11:52:47,831 DEBUG [restartedMain] org.springframework.core.log.CompositeLog: Response 200 OK
```

Note: in my case, adding or disabling this value, isn't making any difference, i am getting the auth token anyway.

```
//headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
```

Comment: The problem was that you where sending the body as headers, and not sure what `reqBodyData` was. But due to this it was selection the wrong message encoder. Nonentheless you are propably better of with explicitly setting the content-type to be sure (you also did that more-or-less with `-d` using curl ).

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the documentation for [`HttpEntity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html) you will see that you are using the wrong constructor.

```
entity = new HttpEntity<>(reqBodyData, bodyParamMap);
```

You are passing the arguments you want to use as the body (`bodyParamMap`) as headers (as the second argument is the headers to be used for the request). In fact you aren't even using the `HttpHeaders` for the request as you aren't passing them to the `HttpEntity`. I'm  not sure what the `reqBodyData` is but probably a `toString` of the `bodyParamMap`.

What you should have been doing is the following

```
entity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyParamMap, headers);
```

As `HttpHeaders` impements `MultiValueMap` you can directly use them in the constructor. You also want to pass the `bodyParamMap` as is.

**NOTE:** I would also suggest to explictly set the `Content-Type` on the `HttpHeaders` so you are sure what is being send.

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
```

Thus the total resulting code should look like

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

MultiValueMap<String, String> bodyParamMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
bodyParamMap.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
bodyParamMap.add("client_id", "nu5yzeth9tektzf5egxuntp7");
bodyParamMap.add("client_secret", "uP2Xvr6SCKYgXgxxJsv2QkUG");

entity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyParamMap, headers);

restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, TokenDTO.class)
```

**NOTE:** You shouldn't be constructing a single use `RestTemplate` but you rather want to configure that once and inject that into your class.

Comment: Thank you @M. Deinum, I didn't know a few things, you share with me. Although, I solved my problem, before your answer, but your one is in more detail and have some points, which can really help others.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by post https://stackoverflow.com/a/49127760/11226302

You should set the request content type in header as;
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

Hope this helps!